# Правописание гласных в корне (в слове "упоминать"?)

Tags: орфография

Каким правилом нужно руководствоваться при написании гласной "и" в слове "упоминать"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это чередование корней на -ИМ, -ИН и -Я :

помин/а/ть//помя/ну/ть, поним/а/ть/поня/ть и т.д. Правило такое же, как во всех чередованиях на и/е, например, бир/бер, так и здесь помин/помя: если за корнем суфф. -а-, пиши -И-.

Я-то ведь из ЯТЬ, как и Е, потому одно правило.

Answer (score 0):

Проверочное - поминки. Это для школы вполне сойдет.

//====
Не для школы.
На самом же деле исторически это очень сложный случай чередования в корне и его сращения с суффиксом. "ИМ" - "Я". "ИН" здесь вообще не является  историческим корнем, но частью древнего суффикса. Но это суровая академическая действительность. Вряд ли кто из нефилологов о том будет сильно переживать, ибо произошло переразложение, в современной действительности корент "помин" вполне годен. Но с чередованием "Поминать" - "помянуть".
Какой конкретно точки зрения придерживаться, лучше уточнить у преподавателя.

Comment: Да? не знал. Ну тогда напишите это как ответ, я свой уберу.

Comment: @Людмила, я это правило знаю, но где здесь чередование а(я)/им(ин), как в понять/понимать? Здесь ян/ин, или это то же самое?

Comment: _natturtle: ...это правило знаю, но где здесь чередование а(**я**)/им(**ин**)? Здесь ян/ин..._ === 

Нет, здесь не _**ян**_. В корнях слов _упом**ин**ать/упом**я**нуть чередование _**-ин-/я**_  ("ну" в **упомянуть** -- суффикс).

Comment: @slava1947 А корень помин/помя или мин/мя?

Comment: _natturtle:  А корень помин/помя или мин/мя?_ === 
У разных словаристов -- по-разному. Некоторые корнем считают _**мин/мя**_, некоторые -- _**помин/помя**_. Точное выделение корня для самого правила несущественно.